# adapter teaming and multiple switches

Tags: cisco, switch, network-teaming

I have a mix of Cisco 3750 and 3650 switches. The switches are connected with EtherChannel trunks. I am not using the StackWise feature of the 3750's.

For redundancy, I would like to enable adapter teaming on my HP servers and connect each server to multiple switches. I know that with no additional configuration on the switches, this gets me transmit load balancing and fault tolerance.

Is there a configuration that also gets me receive load balancing?

(I saw [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406672/link-bonding-across-multiple-switches), which is essentially the same as mine, except I'm going one step further: Does Cisco offer anything that allows adapter teaming across multiple switches without using StackWise?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature exists, but not on your switches - it's a Nexus thing.  See [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps9441/ps9670/configuration_guide_c07-543563.html).