# Windows 2012 to HP Procurve redundancy across multiple switches - multi-switch LACP?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, hp-procurve

We are looking to have our Windows 2012 server(s) connected to two separate switches, so that if one switch goes down the server(s) can still be accessed on the same IP address from the switch that is still alive.

I understand from [here that LACP doesn't bond across multiple switches](https://serverfault.com/questions/404400/does-a-single-lacp-channel-over-multiple-switches-increase-redundancy).

I see also Windows Server 2012 supports NIC teaming, but only to an [individual switch with as per this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/16/nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012-do-i-need-to-configure-my-switch.aspx#.UderVCSoVok).

My questions are:

1. Does HP Procurve (2500 series and up) support teaming across multiple switches for redundancy, if so how would one configure this?
2. Would the configuration on the switch affect the teaming config for Windows Server 2012, or would we just set the teaming mode on the server to LACP?

Comment: The link re. teaming specifically says " configuring NIC Teaming in "Switch Independent" mode, the teaming configuration will work with any Ethernet switches - even non-intelligent switches" and then goes on to describe 2 different situations. Why the statement "supports NIC teaming only to an individual switch?